# Problem to change bundle ID in crashlitycs

Tags: ios, crashlytics

We have some problems with the statistics of crashlitycs. We deliver the build to the customer and they change the provisionings profile,bundle ID,etc. in order to publish the app. When the customer does it, we are not able to get statistics of crashlitycs.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. If the app is being re-signed, then we're likely not seeing the build of the app with the new bundle id or package name in order to activate the app. There is a two step activation process, a build of the app with Fabric enable and a run of the app in order to enable it. The customer needs to do a build and run of the app.